# Implementing deutsch_problem(seed=None) and deutsch() from qiskit text

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I'm attempting to work through the exercise at the end of https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-gates/phase-kickback#phase-8-0 where I am to build and implement Deutsch's algorithm.  I understand that `deutsch_problem(seed=None)` will randomly determine which function is in the black box, but I am not sure how to implement it using Python coding in the `def deutsch(function)`.

My attempt is below and though I have not yet run this on `qasm_simulator` to see what result I get, I feel that since `qc.draw()` only gives me the circuit leading up to the black-box, something must be incorrect.

## My attempt

```
    # My code within def deutsch(function):
    deutsch_problem(seed=None)    #I THINK this randomly decides which of the 4 functions are in the black box
   
    #The next three lines are my attempt to turn the random function into a unitary for the circuit
    usim = Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')
    qobj = assemble(problem)  
    unitary = usim.run(qobj).result().get_unitary()
    
    #The next section builds Deutsch's algorithm to measure the outcome
    qc=QuantumCircuit(2,1)
    qc.x(1)
    qc.h([0,1])
    qc.compose(unitary)
    qc.h(0)
    qc.measure(0,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it, I tried to append gate directly with to_gate, remember to transpile or decompose the label gate before run simulator.
if you want to get unitary of the gate, you can use Operator directly

````
def deutsch(function):
    """Implements Deutsch's algorithm.

    Args:
        function (QuantumCircuit): Deutsch function to solve.
            Must be a 2-qubit circuit, and either balanced,
            or constant.
    Returns:
        bool: True if the circuit is balanced, otherwise False.
    """

    # your code hereqc=QuantumCircuit(2,1)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(2,1)
    qc.x(1)
    qc.h([0,1])
    qc.barrier()
    ################## Three way to append the deutsch_problem()
    qc.append(problem.to_gate(label='unitary'),[0,1])
    #qc.append(Operator(problem),[0,1])
    #qc.unitary(Operator(problem),[0,1])
    ###################
    qc.barrier()
    qc.h(0)
    qc.measure(0,0)
    qc = qc.decompose('unitary')
    display(qc.draw())
    svsim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
    #qc = transpile(qc,svsim)
    final_state = svsim.run(qc).result().get_counts()#.get_statevector()
    final_state = list(final_state.keys())[0]
    if final_state == '0':
      return 'constant'
    if final_state == '1':
      return 'balance'
from qiskit import Aer, assemble
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
problem =deutsch_problem()
#display(problem.draw())
deutsch(problem)
    
```
````

Comment: Thank you so much!  Much of python is still new and I had not yet seen append, to_gate, Operator(), ... so this has taught me more than I had hoped!

Comment: also don't forget the decompose and transpile step for the label gate(oracle), otherwise simulation will pop up error. @PGibbon